# Как вывести время при определенной дате?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, блин ребята выручайте.. потратил кучу времени на данное решение.. мозг уже поплыл...

У меня есть такой JSON на выходе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть такие две таблицы откуда берутся данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
мой код

```html
public function getJSON($shedule){

        $range = [
                  ['start' => $this->morning_work_hours_from, 'end' => $this->morning_work_hours_before] ,
                  ['start' => $this->afternoon_work_hours_from, 'end' => $this->afternoon_work_hours_before]
            ];
        $data = array_map(function($s) use ($range){
                     return [
                            'day' => $s,
                            'timeRangers' => $range
                        ];
                  }, $shedule);

        $result = ['schedule' => $data];

        dd( $shedule, $range, $data, $result);

        return json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Может время не вычитается, потому что не в том массиве ищете? Функция `dd()` вроде как выполняет `dump & die`, собственно - это последняя строчка кода, перед остановкой скрипта, и `return json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` не выполнится никогда.

Comment: да там просто дд стоит. Без нее джейсон будет что на 1 скрине